# How can I warp text 40 degrees. Like a partial cylinder

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Trying to do something like what's at the link below. but with text and other flat objects. Simple Deform bend is close but not what I'm looking for.

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3045130

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do these text and other flat objects have enough geometry to be bent properly? You say, _Simply Deform_ is close, can you provide a screenshot to show what you got?

Comment: so do you want this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MOOT.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, add your text, rotate it so it's "upright". Convert it to a mesh, and notice in wireframe mode that the topology looks like garbage:

[image: Tex1]

Add a Decimate Modifier set to *Planar* to clean (most of it) up. Good enough for now. Apply the modifier.

[image: Text2]

Enter edit mode and select the whole mesh. Select the *Spin Tool* from the bar on the left.

[image: Text3]

Use one of the orthographic perspectives (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>) to get a perfect side view. Position your *3D Cursor* directly below your text with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> (3D cursor acts as pivot point for Spin Tool by default).

[image: Text4]

Click and hold down your mouse and start turning the mesh. You can hold Ctrl to make it step  by increment.

[image: Text5]

Inset all the front faces so you can shade smooth without artifacts.

[image: Text6]

Voila

[image: Text7]

EDIT - Sorry, I just re-read your question and saw you said 45 degrees and not 90. Here's a pic showing 45. I also added a material, a base and some ambient occlusion so it looks less like dental clay.

[image: Text8]

Here it is with the text from your example image along with a simple material consisting of a Bumped Noise Texture (to give it that bumpy, 3D-printed look), and some Subsurface Scattering to make it look a bit like plastic.

[image: Text9]

Comment: Or, I guess, a Screw modifier for a  non-destructive version? Same thing.

Comment: Actually he said 40 degrees, not 45  But I would do it like that, too. Or add loop cuts if I already had geometry that I would like to keep, to get more geometry to work with.

Comment: Yeah it's not quite 90 or 45 the example I showed somewhere in between but thanks for this. Spin tool was what I was looking for really. With that I can spin any object that is semi flat. Using this with 3d printing for table nameplates or plaques. So once I get the mesh I'm good to go. But you made it look like real. You guys always impress me. So much to know so little time.

Answer (score 7):

As Gordon says, you need enough topology to be able to bend your font. What you can do is create your text, convert to mesh, extrude a bit, <kbd>Shift</kbd> to repeat the extrusion:

[image]

Create an empty close to your object. Give your object a *Simple Deform* modifier on *Bend* mode, *Angle* > -90°, with the empty as *Origin*:

[image]

Rotate the empty on X (use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to rotate 5° by 5°), move it until you have the correct shape:

[image]

Right click on your object and *Shade Smooth*, in the *Object Data* panel > *Normals*, enable *Auto Smooth*:

[image]

If you move the empty you can change the rotation center:

[image]

Comment: This wasn't quite it but I really like this too.

Comment: hello, what do you mean? you can do exactly what you wanted with this method but Christopher's is probably faster  ;)